# Cannot replicate crash experience by App Review team (logs included)

Tags: ios, crash, in-app-purchase, crash-reports

I'm currently trying to add an in-app purchase to my project.  A view is loaded with three buttons: one to cancel, one to restore previous purchase, and one to make the purchase.  Using the sandbox environment, I thought I had tried every combination of these buttons in different scenarios (different devices, no internet connection, weak internet connection, etc.).  Somehow, though, the binary was rejected because it crashed on the reviewer trying to make the purchase.

I did get the following crash log, but I'm fairly new to dissecting these and none of the methods/objects immediately stood out to me.  Is there something obvious that I might be missing?? I'd really appreciate any help!

**Edited to include the top portion of the log:**

```
Incident Identifier: 3E8900C5-0D48-4083-896D-0F89CC96A92E
CrashReporter Key:   e92ad99d34bee961df4775e147c1c8a0872ab819
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:         AppName [6619]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/2F1E3034-9499-4CDD-95DE-41F5A904A00D/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:      AppName
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-05-10 13:15:53.042 -0700
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.4 (10B350)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3451f3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c21a95e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34522f2c -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 180
3   CoreFoundation                  0x34521648 ___forwarding___ + 388
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34479204 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   UIKit                           0x36419082 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 66
6   UIKit                           0x36419036 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
7   UIKit                           0x36419010 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
8   UIKit                           0x364188c6 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
9   UIKit                           0x36418db4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
10  UIKit                           0x363415f4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
11  UIKit                           0x3632e8dc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
12  UIKit                           0x3632e1ea _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
13  GraphicsServices                0x380465f2 _PurpleEventCallback + 586
14  GraphicsServices                0x38046222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
15  CoreFoundation                  0x344f43e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
16  CoreFoundation                  0x344f4386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
17  CoreFoundation                  0x344f320a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
18  CoreFoundation                  0x34466238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
19  CoreFoundation                  0x344660c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
20  GraphicsServices                0x38045336 GSEventRunModal + 70
21  UIKit                           0x363822b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
22  AppName                         0x00046c86 main (main.m:16)
23  AppName                         0x00046c3c start + 36


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c70e350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c684fb2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6c1366 abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bc69dda abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bc67094 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c21aa58 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bc67118 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bc671b0 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3bc68626 __cxa_rethrow + 90
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c21a9b0 objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3446629c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x344660c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x38045336 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x363822b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  AppName                         0x00046c86 main (main.m:16)
15  AppName                         0x00046c3c start + 36

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6fe5d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c639d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c635374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c70ed98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c65cad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c65c7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c65c680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6fde30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6fdfd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x344f42b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x344f302c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34466238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x344660c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x3a46e390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6670de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c666fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c70ed98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c65cad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c65c7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c65c680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6fde30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6fdfd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x344f42b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x344f302c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34466238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x344660c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x34db3888 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x34e3722c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6670de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c666fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c70e594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x344f8474 __CFSocketManager + 676
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6670de _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c666fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3e1d0524
r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3e1d0b78      r6: 0x1d8c8434      r7: 0x2fdbba34
r8: 0x1d8c8410    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x36818040
ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdbba28      lr: 0x3c684fb7      pc: 0x3c70e350
```

Comment: The error is about an unrecognized selector being called when the user tapped on something (a `UIButton` or `UIBarButton` perhaps). There should be an actual error in the crash log showing the error message. At that message to your question.

Comment: That's what I was hoping! Usually there is something like "UIViewController doesNotRecognizeSelect:...", but I don't see anything that specific.  The line: "-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 180" stands out, but I'm not too sure what NSObject(NSObject) means.  Any idea?

Comment: Paste in the whole start of the crash log up to the start of the first thread stack trace.

Comment: Sorry about that - just updated it - that's everything except for the "Binary images" at the bottom of the .crash report.

Comment: That's a tough one. Without knowing the actual error message, and no reference to your own code, there's not much to go on. Your best option is to test your app on an iPhone 5 with 6.1.4 and try many different permutations of in-app purchases. Tapping on some control caused the problem. But it's not in your code or there was a memory issue causing a method to be called on the wrong object.

Comment: Yeah, it's driving me nuts.  Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Wild idea: check the selectors you assign as target actions to your buttons, if the have the correct signature everywhere. Maybe you forgot a `:`, or added one at a point where you shouldn't. E.g. `@selector(myAction:)` instead of `@selector(myAction)`

Comment: No luck there, but thanks for the idea.  It just blows my mind that I cannot reproduce it, especially when the IAP view just has three buttons (there are only so many different ways to interact with it!).  

I did heavily modify UIIntroductionView as a way to showcase the benefits of the purchase (added the buttons at the bottom of the view).  I have a feeling there is something I missed and it's likely that I'll just start from scratch with a new VC instead of waste much more time on this.